# Hybrid app automation using appium with selenium

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I  trying to automate a hybrid app using the appium-selenium setup. 
I  facing problem in getting the object properties. I am using ui automator to identify elements but it is unable to do the job. It is only identifying the outer or parent frame of the app and doesn't go beyond that.

My appium version : 1.3.4.1
Chromedriver version: 2.4

I tried in both emulators (Genymotion) and physical devices.

Device environment: Android 4.2 above

For handling hybrid apps we have to switch the contexts between Native view and Webview according to our needs.

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
    for (String contextName : contextNames) {
        // prints out something like NATIVE_APP or WEBVIEW_*
        System.out.println(contextName);
    }
    driver.context(contextNames.toArray()[1].toString()); // set context to
                                                            // WEBVIEW_*
```

But for Hybrid apps (developed using Angulas JS in my case) i could not find any tool to get the object properties. Only way i could find in using the inspect element feature of chrome and getting the xpath. However i was able to use inspect element only on emulators(genymotion). It did not work on real devices for me.

Would be good if any one could shed some more light on that area.

Comment: Make sure you appium server should be OFF when you are trying to get object properties using UI automator.

Comment: Tried after shutting  down Appium. Still not able to get object properties

Comment: what error you getting??

Comment: i am not getting any errors. The UI Automator is capturing screenshot of the app in the emulator but when i hover the mouse on various elements it doesnot identify any element in the screenshot. It only identifies the entire frame.

Comment: does your APK is from live server? or local?

Comment: my apk is installed in the emulator (local)

Comment: No , I am talking about its data and all coming from server or from local?

Comment: the data is coming from server. For the native version of the app also the data was coming from server but i was able to get properties using UI Automator.

Comment: any answers from any body??

Comment: Make sure your android version is updated.

Comment: I have the updated android version

Comment: ok now all things working fine.?

Comment: no still i got the same problem.  If you want I can give u a snapshot comparing both native and Hybrid App property detection in UI Automator

Comment: please upload screenshots..

Comment: Vir, I edited your 'answer' into your question. Responses to should only be for actual answers, not followups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the Appium Inspector to find the xpath of the element, and then call xpath within your test cases.

Appium also contains a step to switch contexts between native and web. I believe it is

```
switch_context(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither uiautomator nor Appium will help you to identify webview elements.

**— You can do this with Chrome Developer tools**, look at [Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) guide. It will work for hybrid apps as well.